# Does the R anova() or car::Anova() care of the type 1 error being a series of LR tests over nested models?

Tags: anova, likelihood-ratio

As in the question. Isn't it that the output of anova(model, model_reduced) or car::Anova(model, type=3) makes the problem of multiple comparisons? What about the aov(), which is type 1 ANOVA, but still reports the main and interaction effects? We get a series of effects with p-values next to each of them. Should the p-values be additionally adjusted for multiplicity, or are they already adjusted?

Comment: @JTH, post as answer?

Comment: @BenBolker promoted my comment to an answer and deleted the comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

aov/anova ouputs are not adjusted for multiple comparisons. This is actually a good thing. Comparison adjustments are not always required, and different adjustments are favored in different situations. So the software is leaving the analyst in charge and not making any assumptions on her behalf.